# Count rows of DataGridView where Combox has value x

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using a count function to count the rows of my DataGridView which looks like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            int noOfRows = dataGridTable.RowCount;
            noOfRows--;
            textBox1.Text = noOfRows.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Now i have a Combox in one of the Columns of my DataGridView. For Example my Combox includes Yes or No. My function works well to count the rows, but now i only want to count the rows where in the Combox Yes is selected. How can i do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `Value` of each `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, and count only the "Yes" values:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int row = 0; row < _dgv.Rows.Count; ++row)
  {
    if (_dgv.Rows[row].Cells[_comboBoxColumnNumberOrName].Value == "Yes")
    {
      count++;
    }
  }

  textBox1.Text = $"{count}";
}
```

Comment: It doesnt work, it shows a error message: int contains no definition for cells

Comment: @Adir Edited, forgot to index the Row

Comment: Thanks for your help again @mmathis. But now i have the problem that i got red underlined warning at my Colum declaration which says: conversion from "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn" to "int" not possible.
If I put it in quotation marks a green line will appear which says: unintended comparison. I run the application and in both versions the function works but if i change the ComboBox from yes to no it decreases but doesn´t increases if i put it to yes again.

Comment: I don't have a running example in front of me, so you might need to call `ToString()` on the `Value` or other minor edits to resolve compilation errors.

Comment: I looked at the compiler message on the microsoft page and attached a string before the  if function and now it work´s fine. Many thanks for your help @mmathis.

Ended up like this:
if ((string)_dgv.Rows[row].Cells[_comboBoxColumnNumberOrName].Value == "Yes")